# (something rubs off on people) vs. the same relation from the other direction

Tags: idiom-request

I like the idiom that something "rubs off" on people but I am wondering if there is an idiom with the same meaning but from the other direction; in other words, I mean with the *meaning that people begin to have a positive attitude -or any other thing for that matter- from it* as in the quote below.

This entry is from Merriam Webster

> **rub off**
>
> often used figuratively
>
> ▪*Her positive attitude rubbed off on other people.* **[=other people
>   began to have a positive attitude from being around her]**
>
> ▪*I wish some of your good luck would rub off on me.* [=I wish that I
>   would start having good luck too]

Comment: I think the word *infectious* might be what you want -- it can describe peoples' attitudes rubbing off on others.  "*Her positive attitude was infectious*."  It wouldn't really be used with things that aren't attitudes, like "good luck."

Comment: Don't fall into the trap of assuming that just because one dictionary example specifically conveys the *meaning that people begin to have a positive attitude or other thing for that matter from it* it always has that sense. Bad habits can rub off onto others just as much as good habits. (Note that *infectious*, often applied to *laughter*, obviously also has potentially negative associations simply because of its *literal* meaning).

Comment: Also don't confuse *rub off on[to] others* with *rub [others] up **the wrong way*** (which is *always* bad).

Comment: Rub off on someone but rub someone the wrong way. I have never seen: rub up the wrong way.

Comment: To _rub up_ is a chiefly British idiom. It might not be well-understood in the U.S., and I've only heard it in the sense of _remind_ or _refresh one's memory._ Some [**sources**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rub+up) agree with that, but I'll take @FumbleFingers 's word most days.

Comment: @P. E. Dant: I didn't realise that, but a check check comparing AmE / BrE corpuses on Google Books / NGrams shows me that whereas ***rubbed off on him*** is about equally common in both, ***rubbed him up the wrong [way]*** is far less common in AmE. The former seems to go back 150+ years, but it looks like the latter is essentially a post-WW2 usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This side of the pond, we might _bone up_ on a subject where _rub up_ would serve yonder.

Comment: @P. E. Dant: I'm not aware of *bone up* (meaning *study intensively,* to me) ever being equivalent to *rub up* (always *...the wrong way*, always meaning *irritate*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers You must not be sufficiently informal! [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rub--up) has: 22. **rub up,** _British Informal._ to refresh one's memory of (a subject, language, etc.). Anecdotally, I've heard it used that way in Blighty meself, although it was 20 years ago.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This is fascinating. It seems that since I heard this usage in ~1965 (on Carnaby St. a _bit_ more than 20 years ago, I suppose, in "I'll have a rub up on that lyric") it has fallen completely out of use. It's still in various phrasal verb lists and even in OED, but I can't find a single contemporary example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Once, when I commented that a person had an "infectious smile", a waggish friend responded: _"Yeah, it makes me sick."_

Comment: @P. E. Dant:: The full OED's entry for that sense of **rub up** says *"intr. Now **rare**"* (they define it as synonymous with ***to brush up***, which is the form I'm familiar with). Apparently it's also used for "to masturbate", which is transparent enough, but I didn't know that one either. I've lived a sheltered life, obviously! *Sick* joke, btw,